# Limit of a flow of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\phi_t(x)$ be a solution of $x'=f(x)$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $ f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, and $f\in C^1.$ If 
$\lim_{t\to\infty}{\phi_t(x)}=x_0$, then $f(x_0)=0.$

Is this statement true???

Comment: Think about what would happen if $f(x_0)\ne0$. How could any orbit possibly approach $x_0$?

Answer (score 1):

- $\lim_{t\to\infty} x'(t)$ exists and has the value $f(x_0)$ since as $t\to\infty$ so $x(t)\to x_0$ and $x'(t)=f(x(t))\to f(x_0)$.
- $x(n+1)-x(n)=x'(n+\theta_n)=f(x(n+\theta_n))$ with $\theta_n\in(0,1)$.

  The limit for $n\to\infty$ on the left side is zero, thus the limit on the right side must be zero too.

Comment: How do we prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x'(t)$ exists?

Comment: Because $f$ is continuous and $x'(t)=f(x(t))$. Or just extend the second identity to $…=f(x(n+θ_n))$, then you have all in one line, $0=f(\lim_{n\to\infty}x(n+θ_n))=f(x_0)$.

Comment: Thank you so much.

As I understand, we might not have $\lim_{t\to\infty} x'(t)$, but we can choose a sequence of $t_n\to\infty$ which $x'(t_n)\to 0.$ And use this to get $f(x_0)=0$.

Comment: As $x(t)\to x_0$, so $x'(t)=f(x(t))\to f(x_0)$, there is no sequence selection necessary. But for at least one sequence we know that the limit is $0$.